# Travelling to the UK as a South African citizen - evidence for funds?

Tags: visas, uk, south-african-citizens

I'm a South African looking to go to the UK on a visitor visa for 6 months and will be staying with friends and family. On the visa page they say you need to prove you can support your self financially - I just wanted to know how much money I need and what if I have a family member that is going to support me financially on the trip, do they still need to put the money into my account or do I give their details when applying for the visa?

Comment: What @pnuts said. Also...  They changed the rules such that 3rd parties providing support must live in the UK during your visit.  But yeah, they do not publish a prescribed daily amount of money.

Answer (score 2):

This is common for many countries for visas, and the frustrating thing you realise is - there's no set amount of money.

Generally, you need to show you have 'enough' for the duration of your trip.

So this might include a letter stating you've got accommodation sorted (staying with friends/family), plus money to show you can cover yourself.

What they're looking for is evidence that you've thought your trip through, including emergencies, contingencies and have worked out and have evidence of funds.

If you're being supported by a family member, you're still going to need evidence of the funds - otherwise they have no way of knowing if it's royalty or a broke cousin that's supporting you.

[From one such online British document detailing what to provide](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/270197/sup-docs-settlement.pdf):

> If you are not funding your stay yourself, the person who will fund it
>   should consider supplying the evidence

I suggest having a read of the document for further information as well, but essentially, the responsibility is on you to convince them that you're not going to end up in financial trouble while on your visa in the UK.  Frustrating :/