# What are the requirements needed to visit the UK for 2 weeks?

Tags: visas, uk, south-african-citizens

I'm in a long distance relationship and I want to visit him next year in England. I am new to all this so I need to know what requirements are needed as I'm from South Africa. I will be staying at a hotel there. How much will I approximately need to be accepted into the UK? Also what reason would I have to give to enter?

Comment: `Also what reason would I have to give to enter?` This will be a sticking point. If you say the real reason, they it might be construed as a way to enter UK permanently and you have to show enough proof to show you will return back. And if you lie, anything comes up during the landing interview, you might be denied entry.

Comment: You don't lie. If they catch you in a lie, the consequences tend to be black marks and bans.

Comment: You might find some helpful information in this answer https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/45804/1820

Comment: I'm still confused as to what reason to give, if I do say the truth what if I'm denied visa to the uk. Would a solo travellor be a good enough reason?

Comment: They know about LDR;s and people who contrive a premise. Keeping a secret is disastrous because your premise will not make sense. Play it straight up but recognise that they are reluctant to issue visas for LDR's that have never met in person. Try to lie and you will be refused on a credibility hit which does profound damage to future travel. You have a great answer below, please check it as "accepted", many thanks.

Comment: So if they deny me a visa to the uk if I say the truth then what do I do?

Comment: @Melisha if that happens then you would be GLAD that you did not get a refusal that affected your credibility. Credibility problems are the very worst to fix.

Answer (score 5):

You will require a [Standard Visitors Visa](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/overview).

There is no specific amount that you require. You are required to prove that you have adequate ties to South Africa and that you will abide by your visitors visa. You will need to show that you have adequate financial support for such a holiday.

You need to prove that your ties are strong enough independent of your sponsor.

From what I've read here, government's are cautious to give visas to individuals who have never met their sponsor in person. This is to prevent human trafficking and so forth.

Comment: I would strengthen the "without relying too much on your sponsor" -- a local sponsor **cannot be relied on _at all_** for establishing ties to a home country.

Comment: I agree with you there @HenningMakholm.

Comment: Exactly what kind of proof? What documents are needed?

Comment: It depends on your circumstances. Please see the guidance provided here: https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf